# How many players have finished 8th or better in major championships during the same season?

Tags: golf

In [this article](https://www.espn.com/golf/story/_/id/34293478/pga-tour-power-rankings-cameron-smith-rises-rory-mcilroy-surges-liv-players-exit), Rory McIlroy is credited as the "third player in the past 50 years to finish eighth or better in all four majors in the same season." However, I was able to find five:

1. Tiger Woods (5-1-1-1 in 2000, 1-2-1-T4 in 2005)
2. Phil Mickelson (1-2-3-T6 in 2004)
3. Rickie Fowler (T5-T2-T2-T3 in 2014)
4. Jon Rahm (T5-T8-1-3 in 2021)
5. Rory McIlroy (2-8-T5-3 in 2022)

Do any other such seasons exist?

Answer (score 3):

[Jordan Spieth 2015](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_Spieth#Results_timeline)

| Major | Finish |
| --- | --- |
| Masters | 1 |
| US Open | 1 |
| Open Championship | T4 |
| PGA Championship | 2 |

[Brooks Koepka 2019](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brooks_Koepka#Results_timeline)

| Major | Finish |
| --- | --- |
| Masters | T2 |
| PGA Championship | 1 |
| US Open | 2 |
| Open Championship | T4 |